# onchange handler not displaying together with my if:true directive

Tags: lightning-web-components, conditional

I am doing this udemy course for LWC Development and I am stuck on the part for conditional rendering. My goal is that I should be able to show and hide the div with the use if `if:true` and `if:false` directives but for some reason, I am not able to do it. I am sharing my html & js code below:

HTML:

```
    <lightning-input type="checkbox" label="Show Div" onchange={showDivHandler}>
        <template if:true={displayDiv}>
            <div>Hello again</div>
        </template>
        <template if:false={displayDiv}>
            <div>I am not here</div>
        </template>
    </lightning-input>
</template>
```

JS:

```
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';
 
 export default class ConditionRenderingExample extends LightningElement {
     @track displayDiv = false;
  
     showDivHandler(event) {
         this.displayDiv = event.target.checked;
     }
 }
```

I have tried adding `@track` in hopes of making the code work. Any explanations behind this would be really helpful as I have been stuck on this for 2 days already. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are almost there John, the only change you need to do is move the `<template>` tags outside the `<lightning-input type="checkbox">`, as follow:

```
<template>
    <lightning-input type="checkbox" label="Show Div" onchange={showDivHandler}>
    </lightning-input>
    <template if:true={displayDiv}>
        <div>Hello again</div>
    </template>
    <template if:false={displayDiv}>
        <div>I am not here</div>
    </template>
</template>
```

Comment: thanks!!! Worked like magic!! why is that the case? why do we need to not enclose it within the `<lightning-input type="checkbox">` tag?

Comment: glad it helped! and the reason why is because there are some html elements that are defined as `void elements` which means: _they are elements whose content model never allows it to have contents under any circumstances._ you can read more about it [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html-markup-20110113/syntax.html#syntax-elements) and you will find which elements do/do not support content within their bodies.